# Advanced techniques needed to solve a difficult integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

I am looking to solve the following integral.

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2}e^{bx} dx$.

I have made an attempt using the differentiation under the integral sign method and I got the following:

$b\ln(b)-\frac{1}{2}b-\frac{1}{2}b\ln(b^2+a^2)-\frac{1}{2}a\arctan(\frac{b}{a})$. eqn(2)

I think the above answer is incorrect because I know that if b=0, then

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}|a|$

however, if I let b$\rightarrow$0 in  eqn(2) my result is

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2}e^{bx} dx = 0$.

I would appreciate any assistance provided. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think b*log(b) -> 0

Comment: I know few integral like that can be solved with complex functions. (but usually it should be rational function). would you allow using some complex analysis ? see for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710404/real-integral-using-complex-methods

Comment: What about de developing $\frac{1-\cos ax}{x^2}$ in entire series?

Comment: I wonder if the equation $(2)$ should not be $$\frac{1}{2} b \log \left(1+\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)-a \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$ which leads to the correct limit.

Comment: I agree with the expression proposed by Claude Leibovici.

Answer (score 3):

$b \lt 0$ for convergence, so rewrite for $b=-c$ as

$$2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{\sin^2{(a x/2)}}{x^2} e^{-c x} \theta(x) $$

where $\theta(x) = 0$ when $x \lt 0$ and $1$ when $x \gt 0$.

We can use Parseval's equality to evaluate this integral.  Parseval states that, if $f$ and $g$ have respective Fourier transforms $F$ and $G$, then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) g^*(x) = \frac1{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, F(k) G^*(k) $$

$$f(x) = 2 \frac{\sin^2{(a x/2)}}{x^2} \implies F(k) = \pi \left (a-|k| \right ) \theta(a-|k|)$$

$$g(x) = e^{-c x} \theta(x)  \implies G(k) = \frac1{c+i k} $$

The integral is then

$$\begin{align}\frac12 \int_{-a}^a dk \frac{a-|k|}{c-i k}  &= \frac{a}{2} \int_{-a}^a \frac{dk}{c-i k} + \frac12 \int_0^a dk \, k \left ( \frac1{c-i k} + \frac1{c+i k}\right ) \\ &= i \frac{a}{2} \log{\left (\frac{a+i c}{-a+i c}  \right )}+ c \int_0^a dk \, \frac{k}{c^2+k^2} \\ &= a \arctan{\frac{a}{c} }+ \frac{c}{2} \log{\left (1+\frac{c^2}{a^2} \right)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Why downvotes for a so nice answer ?

Comment: Thank you Ron Gordon. I appreciate your help.

Comment: That was brilliant! :)

Comment: Thanks @Bruce.  If you found the solution useful, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

b bust be negative to ensure the integral convergence. Then if we write the value of the integral we get b in the denominator all through. What you have done is you eliminated the denominators and you know that you want the denominator to be 0. There is no mistake.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mathematica the answer for $b<0$ and $a$ real is :
$$\frac{1}{2}b \log(a^2+b^2) -b \log(-b) - |a|\arctan \left(\frac{|a|}{b}\right)$$
which indeed converges to the value $|a|\frac{\pi}{2}$ when $b \rightarrow 0$. It is closed to you expression but not exactly the same.

What exactly did you do with differentiation under the integral ? For example, using this kind of method, you have to use some inital value to fix your integration constants. Which one did you use ?

Comment: Where are you ? Your profile is less explicit than mine. Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi. I'm a french student, currently doing an internship in the UK, if this is what you're asking (indeed my profile is quite empty, but I'm new on the forum) :)

Comment: So, welcome here ! It is a fantastic site ! By the way, I am in Pau. Cheers :-)